# Cesium GeometryInstance - how to set multicolors

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I have the following code that creates triangles (forming an object) based on a coordinate list. I would like to color each triangle with a different color. Currently, all triangles have the same color. Is that possible?

It seems like there is no option to set color list instead of one color.

```
for (j = 0; j < NumberOfObjects; j++) {
var mypositions = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights(AllObjectCoordinates[j]);
var numPositions = mypositions.length;

var pos = new Float64Array(numPositions * 3);
var normals = new Float32Array(numPositions * 3);
for (var i = 0; i < numPositions; ++i) {
  pos[i * 3] = mypositions[i].x;
  pos[i * 3 + 1] = mypositions[i].y;
  pos[i * 3 + 2] = mypositions[i].z;
  normals[i * 3] = 1;
  normals[i * 3 + 1] = 0;
  normals[i * 3 + 2] = 0;
}

var geometry = new Cesium.Geometry({
vertexFormat : Cesium.VertexFormat.ALL,
  attributes: {
    position: new Cesium.GeometryAttribute({
      componentDatatype: Cesium.ComponentDatatype.DOUBLE, // not FLOAT
      componentsPerAttribute: 3,
      values: pos
    }),
    normal: new Cesium.GeometryAttribute({
      componentDatatype: Cesium.ComponentDatatype.FLOAT,
      componentsPerAttribute: 3,
      values: normals
    }),


  },

  indices: new Uint32Array(Array.apply(null, {length: (numPositions)}).map(Number.call, Number)),
  primitiveType: Cesium.PrimitiveType.TRIANGLES,
  boundingSphere: Cesium.BoundingSphere.fromVertices(pos)
});
Cesium.GeometryPipeline.computeNormal(geometry);



var myInstance = new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
  geometry: geometry,
  attributes: {
 color: new Cesium.ColorGeometryInstanceAttribute.fromColor(Cesium.Color.fromCssColorString("#ffff99"))
  },
  show: new Cesium.ShowGeometryInstanceAttribute(true),
  id : 'Objekat' 
});

var Objekat = viewer.scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.Primitive({
  geometryInstances: [myInstance],
  asynchronous: false,
  appearance: new Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance({
    closed: true,
    translucent: false
  })
  })); 
  }
```